# how to echo out every item in table using PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I want to echo everything from table that matched the criteria, currently it should be 3 rows that match, but it echoes out only 1.

```
public function fetchInventoryItems($user_id)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_owner=? 
AND inventory=?");
        $stmt->execute([$user_id,'1']);
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
        {

            while($userRows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {   

                $itemId = $userRows['item_id'];
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM items_db WHERE 
   item_id=?");
                  $stmt->execute([$itemId]); 

                     while($itemRows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                      {

                          echo '<div  class="dragcontainer inventory" ><div 
  id="'.$itemRows['item_id'].'" class="item '.$itemRows['item_type'].'" 
   style="background-image:url('.$itemRows['item_icon'].')" draggable="true"> 
 </div></div>';    
                       }

              }
           }
      }
      catch(PDOException $e)
      {
          echo $e->getMessage();
      }    
 }
```

first fetch should retrieve 3 rows but the while loop only cycles once.
i guess it has something to do with PDO but i dont know what exactly

Comment: Are you sure the SQL request doesn't only return 1 record? With "item_id=?" it seems normal to get only one item of this id. (Can't be sure without knowing your data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line...

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM items_db WHERE item_id=?");
```

Your overwriting the use of `$stmt` in the outer loop.  Change this and any uses of this version to something else (`$stmt1` would do)...

```
$stmt1= $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM items_db WHERE item_id=?");
```

You could rework both these SQL queries into 1 SQL statement, which would reduce the overhead and stop this sort of issue.

Comment: thanks that solved it, i completely forgot it overwrites it.